# is "little such [noun]" acceptable?

Tags: comparative, quantifiers

Can "little" be used to modify "such + noun"? Does "little such care" sound natural to you?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give us a full sentence please?

Comment: Yes, it can. But I doubt that this is the answer you were hoping for. Provide more detail in your question and you can get a better answer to it.

Comment: What about "He deserve little such care"? It it natural?

Comment: Some examples from Google's book search: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22little%20such%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#lr=lang_en&pws=0&q=%22little+such+care%22&tbm=bks&tbs=lr:lang_1en

Comment: "He *deserves* little such care." is OK.

Comment: "He deserves little such care" is not really grammatical. He hardly deservers such care.

Answer (score 1):

This is acceptable, but only when *little* is used as a quantifier with a non-count noun, not when it is used to indicate size.

> Scholarly writers on social topics should take care to exclude their personal biases. **<sup>ok</sup>Little such care**  is evident in this essay. ... *What is meant, and correctly expressed, is 'little care of this sort'*.
>
> Children as young as eight years old are working here.  **<sup>∗</sup>Little such children** should not be permitted in the mines. ... *What is meant, but incorrectly expressed, is 'such little children' = 'children who are so little'*.

---

<sup>∗</sup> <sub>*marks an ungrammatical utterance.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but it's more proper to write

"**little of** such care"

*or*

"**little in the way of** such care."

By dropping "**of**" the author places added focus on the omission of care.